# Cycle structure of f(x) = 2x mod k

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z},  f(x) = 2x \mod n$ for a fixed $n$. For a given $x$, does the orbit under $f$ eventually reach the fixed point $0$, or is it periodic? This can be handled by generic cycle detection algorithms, but is there a faster way, especially for large $n$?

I think using the fact that $2x \pmod n = 2(x \mod n) \mod n$, an equivalent question would be, does there exist an $i$ such that $2^i x \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the chinese remainder theorem to split your problem into a problem where $n$ is a power of $2$, and a problem where n is odd.

In the case where $n$ is a power of $2$, after enough iterations the function will collapse onto the fixed point.

When $n$ is odd, you can use Fermat's little theorem to show that a power of $2$ can never be congruent to $0$ mod $n$. So in this case it cycles, unless the iteration starts from $0$.

In general for $n$ even, the function cycles iff the initial value isn't divisible by the odd part of $n$, otherwise it converges.